# "The input line is too long" error in a very basic script for no obvious reason

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

The following script

```
cmd /C ""set PATH=nasm\;%PATH%" & "echo %PATH%""
```

Only prints this:

```
The input line is too long.
The input line is too long.
```

Why? How can I fix this?

P. S. This works:

```
cmd /C "echo %PATH%"
```

And this doesn't:

```
cmd /C ""echo %PATH%""
```

Comment: What do you try to solve? Your line will set the path and after returning the path has the original value again

Comment: @jeb: I'm aware of that. I'm setting up the environment for the next command, which is irrelevant for this question so I removed it from the code sample. And I can't run that command because the PATH setup fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With using two double quotes `""`, the cmd.exe expects a single command.
But a command has a limit of ~250 characters.

But you don't want a command named `echo C:\windows\...`.
And your `set path=... & echo %path%` can't work, as the percent expansion is done before the line is executed.

This one should work

```
cmd /v:on /C "set PATH=nasm\;%PATH% & echo ^!PATH^!"
```

But I can't see any reason why you don't use a code block, perhaps with setlocal

```
(
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  "%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
  set "PATH=nasm\;%PATH%"
  echo !PATH!
  endlocal
)
```

If you really need to use `cmd /c` then it can also contains quotes, but not *over* multiple commands

```
cmd /v:on /C ""%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat" & set PATH=nasm\;%PATH% & echo ^!PATH^!"
```

Comment: Thanks, we're getting close. The only problem is that I actually need to run this: `%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat & set PATH=nasm\;%PATH% & echo ^!PATH^!` The problem is that `%VS120COMNTOOLS%` path contains spaces so I need to escape it somehow.

Comment: Put it into quotes? `"%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat" & set PATH=nasm\;%PATH% & echo ^!PATH^!`

Comment: I did! I think now `cmd /C` handles `"%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"`` (the quoted part) as the command and the rest - as its argument(s). See examples here: http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

Comment: The reason I can't use a code block is that I need to call `cmd /C`, and hence I need all the script to be a single line.

Answer (score 10):

The OP's problem differed slightly from mine, but I also had `The input line is too long` error in a very basic script for no obvious reason.

In my case, the reason that it was not obvious is that I had earlier corrupted my environment by recursively setting my Path until it exceeded the permissible size and then I had fixed the issue before attempting to diagnose the error.

Restarting the command prompt was sufficient in this case to get a fresh Path.

To test if you might have done something like this, just display your environment variables by running `set` with no arguments.  In my case, it showed the recursively set Path (much longer than shown here, but you see the repeating parts):

```
C:\dev_build>set
...
Path=C:\qnx660\host\win32\x86\usr\bin;C:\qnx660\.qnx\bin;C:\qnx660\jre\bin;C:\qnx660\host\win32\x86\usr\bin;C:\qnx660\.qnx\bin;C:\qnx660\jre\bin;C:\qnx660\host\win32\x86\usr\bin;C:\qnx660\.qnx\bin;C:\qnx660\jre\bin;C:\qnx660\host\win32\x86\usr\bin;C:\qnx660\.qnx\bin;C:\qnx660\jre\bin;C:\qnx660\host\win32\x86\usr\bin;C:\qnx660\.qnx\bin;C:\qnx660\jre\bin;C:\qnx660\host\win32\x86\usr\bin;C:\qnx660\.qnx\bin;C:\qnx660\jre\bin;C:\qnx660\host\win32\x86\usr\bin;C:\qnx660\.qnx\bin;...
...
```

Any further attempts to do anything to Path gave me `The input line is too long`

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting the 8,192 character command line length limit.

Comment: The command line is the `cmd /C ""set PATH=nasm\;%PATH%" & "echo %PATH%""` line itself, isn't it? It's clearly not very long. And my `%PATH%` is 1340 characters long. Also, I don't think blowing up `%PATH%` is possible with `cmd /C` which creates the new command line interpreter instance every time.

Comment: The line length will be calculated _after_ the expansion of the `%path%` variable

Comment: So 2x the length of `%PATH%` in my case? Still under 3000 characters.

Comment: Please see the P. S. section I've just added to my question. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe You are correct that running it multiple times would not blow up the length because it will get reset between each running of CMD.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and it was actually mis-reported error in the executable name. Had this

```
"C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_151"\bin\java"
```

instead of this

```
"C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\java"
```